# Upgrade cpu to a different family in the same generation

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i5

I recently bought a `Dell Optiplex 7010` and it has cpu model `intel core i5-2400`. I read that the highest processor ever shipped with this motherboard was the `intel core i7-3770`. Does this mean if I intend to upgrade this processor to the `core i7` family, i can install up to `core i7-3770K` or you can only upgrade according to manufacturer documentation?

Comment: I believe this depends on a number of factors, including BIOS support. According to https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/optix/en/optiplex_7010_technical_guidebook.pdf the i7-3770 is supported. IIRC the benefit of the "k" version is for overclocking - something that may not be possible on that motherboard - or at least very difficult  The i7-3770 is a fine CPU, even when not overclocked.

Comment: i7-3770 is _not_ the same generation as i5-2400 and I think support for the i7-3770 doesn't guarantee that i7-3770K will work.

Comment: @davidgo i agree, there issue was raised at dell forum and a staff said the exact same thing, am building a gaming PC thanks

Comment: 2nd and 3rd generation Intel core processors were not compatible with one another.  If you are building a "gaming PC" you might want to stay away from processors from over a decade ago. They were the same socket but they most definitely were NOT compatible.  You will probably not reach your goal with such old outdated unsupported hardware.

Comment: @Ramhound I think that choice is made by the motherboard manufacturer and not us, commenting with some official documentation would greatly be appreciated geez

Comment: according to this link, i should be able to mount a 3770K and all systems go https://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-Intel_(chipsets)/Q77_Express.html